# Which forces are stoping a moving bicycle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, angular-momentum, torque, free-body-diagram

So let's say a bicycle is moving at a constant speed velocity v. And now I apply the brakes, which causes the, say, the front wheel here, to rotate slower, which then in a way makes the friction force higher, but then the rear wheel is still trying to go at the velocity v. Can i now say that the bicycle would stop the when the friction torque is as large as the normal torque, i.e. when the friction torque is as large as  moment of inertia of the wheels times the acceleration?

How exactly are these forces related to each other when I apply the brakes? I am having a very hard time conceptualising this. Also i'm told the there is a difference between applying the front wheel brake and the rare, and why is that?

EDIT: Also is the center of mass of the bicycle important here?

Answer (score 2):

It is friction with the ground which stops the bicycle.  As long as the wheels are rolling, the tire-ground interaction is static friction; if the wheels skid, the force switches to kinetic friction, which offers less horizontal force for the same amount of normal force.

If we model the bicycle as a rigid object, there are *three* torques to consider:

1. The front wheel may rotate around its hub
2. The rear wheel may rotate around its hub
3. The entire bicycle may rotate around some axis, such as one of the tire-to-ground contact points.

In the case where the bicycle is rolling along at constant velocity, and in the limit where the hubs are frictionless, the static friction with the road can be zero.  Note that if the cyclist is exerting a speeding-up torque on the wheels, using the pedals and chain, the friction with the road is what causes the bicycle to accelerate in the forward direction.  Since the road friction can point forward *or* backward, zero has to be allowed as well.  Don’t forget about other cases where the static friction works out to be zero, such as an object which is stationary on a perfectly level surface.

Let’s consider the extreme case where the brakes are strong enough to *lock* the wheels of the bicycle.  The tire-ground interaction is still going to apply a torque, but now it’s acting on the frame of the bicycle.  If both tires stay on the road, it is because the normal force between the road and the front tire becomes larger than the normal force between the road and the rear tire, applying an opposing torque to the frame.  Applying the brakes makes the bicycle want to pitch forward.

But don’t forget that the maximum allowed static friction, and the actual value of the kinetic friction, are both proportional to the normal force.  If you apply only the rear brake, this pitching-forward effect reduces the available braking force.  If you apply only the front brake, the pitching-forward effect *increases* the available braking force. For the same amount of braking force, the rear wheel will skid before the front wheel.

A calculation you can make is whether the front wheel will start to skid before the rear wheel lifts up off of the ground.  For most bicycles, it’s possible to do a “front wheelie” by stopping the front brake hard enough.  In practice this means that it’s impossible to skid the front wheel using the handbrake, because the cyclist feels the rear wheel lift and instinctively eases off the front brake. Favoring the front brake helps the cyclist stop faster and also saves skid wear on the rear tire.

You ask in a comment,

> So the brake torque changes the linear velocity of the bicycle? Then what is the difference between the brake torque and the road torque?

Torques do not change linear velocity; the velocity changes if there is a nonzero linear force.

The brake torque is internal to the bicycle.  Let's split the bicycle into two smaller systems:

1. the frame, which interacts with the front wheel, and
2. the front wheel, which interacts with the frame and the road.

(We'll neglect the back wheel for now.)  There two places where the frame and the front wheel interact with each other: at the brake pads, which are usually at the top of the wheel, and where the fork of the bicycle connects to the axle.
If the bicycle is moving forward and you apply the front brake, there is a Newton's-third-law pair of equal and opposite forces between the front brake pads and the front wheel.  The direction of this force pair is to cause the frame and the front wheel to move closer together: the motion of the front wheel drags the brake pad forward, while the friction of the brake pad slows the motion of the top of the front wheel away from the frame.  The connection to the axle prevents the the frame from actually overtaking the wheel.  These two forces exert a torque on the frame, in the direction of lifting the back wheel.  *If* the speed of the frame decreases, it is because the backwards-pointing force from the fork-axle connection is larger than the front-pointing force on the brake pads.

The wheel, we've already said, is subject to the third-law counterparts of the forces on the frame.  We have already established that, if the speed of the frame decreases, the frame is exerting a net forward force on the wheel.
However, the wheel is also experiencing friction from the road. If the speed of the wheel *also* decreases, it is because the backwards-pointing friction from the road is larger than the forward-pointing force from the frame of the bicycle.

A common intro-physics problem is to imagine a line of boxes on a level floor.  Some external force is pushing the line of boxes from one side, like a grocery-store employee pushing a dozen carts at once in from the parking lot.  Smushed between each pair of boxes is a bathroom scale.  What do all of the scales say?  What's the net force on each box, so that they all accelerate together?  Lots of intro-physics students are stumped by these problems, or surprised by the answers. I think that finding and solving a problem of this sort would help you make sense of your bicycle question.

Comment: Hi thank you for all this...So if i consider both wheels to be rotating around a point, just a point, not a hub or anything like that, and the friction to be non-zero, which torques are responsible for the deaacleration of the bicycle?

Comment: Torques do not cause linear acceleration. The brake applies a slowing torque to the wheel; the road applies a no-don’t-slow-down torque to the wheel. The linear force between the bicycle and the road changes the linear velocity of the bicycle.

Comment: So the brake torque changes the linear velocity of the bicycle? Then what is the difference between the brake torque and the road torque?

Comment: I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the bicycle has constant velocity before using the brakes, the net torque on the wheels is zero. The effect of the brakes on the wheel is a torque that reduces its angular velocity.

If it was a static bicycle of a gym, that would be the whole story.

But it has a linear velocity with respect to the ground. Supposing enough friction to avoid slipping, the decrease of the angular speed results in a friction force on the ground. The reaction from the ground is a backwards force on the wheels. The torque produced by this force tends to keep the previous velocity. The net torque is: $\tau = \tau_b - 2FR$, where $\tau_b$ is the torque from the brakes, $F$ is the backward force from the ground on the wheels, and $R$ is the radius of the wheels.

The (negative) angular acceleration $\alpha$ is proportional to the net torque, and to get the same $\alpha$ for a moving biclycle compared to a stationary one, it is necessary a bigger braking torque.

Comment: So if we apply a big enough braking torque, then there is no need for "minimal braking distance"? Is this correct? And sorry how is this brake torque defined? And in your equation F, i assume is the friction force?

Comment: If we apply too much braking torque, the wheels stop suddenly. In this case the tires slip, and the braking distance depends on the kinetic friction coeficient with the ground.